# Cannot update Powershell object property inside of function

Tags: powershell, function, object

I need to update a PS object property. Following works fine:

```
$myObject = [PSCustomObject]@{
    Name="Fill Me In" }

Write-Output $myObject.Name
$myObject.Name = "Robert Anderson"
Write-Output $myObject.Name
```

But when I place the same code in a function I get an error:

```
$myObject = [PSCustomObject]@{
    Name="Fill Me In" }

function Update-Name {

    param
    (
        [Object[]]$WorkItem
    )

    Write-Output $WorkItem.Name
    $WorkItem.Name = "Robert Anderson"
    Write-Output $WorkItem.Name
}

Update-Name -WorkItem $myObject
```

Error is:

```
> Fill Me In
> The property 'Name' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.
> +     $WorkItem.Name = "Robert Anderson"
> +     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>     + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyAssignmentException
> Fill Me In
```

Comment: You're typing your parameter as `[Object[]]` so you would need to enumerate it before updating the property. Otherwise you're referring to an array not the object to be updated

Comment: Maybe you don't really want that parameter to be an array, in which case you could fix the problem by simply typing it like `param( [Object] $WorkItem )` or even omit the type which is practically the same: `param( $WorkItem )`.

Comment: Can you explain whats the reason behind updating a reference type from a function? Why are you looking to do this? Do note there is likely a better way to approach this

Comment: thank you both for pointing out my mistake, parameter does not to be an array

Answer (score 0):

My mistake was setting the parameter to expect an array of objects when in reality I will only be passing a single object. Changing the parameter to `[Object]$WorkItem` resolved the problem with help from the comments